# Nginx is not preserving the path when using domain name

Tags: nginx, dns

My application is running on Nginx webserver. I can access the application through my server DNS name. Example :

ec2-xxxxxx/**myapp**

If I enter the address without **/myapp**, I can see Nginx 403 Forbidden error.

I have now created a new sub-domain on my Domain control panel and Forwarding the request to the root address.

I can see the 403 error when accessing the sub-domain, **however when I enter *subdomain.mydomain.com/myapp*, I still see the 403 Forbidden error.**  Somehow the relative path is not being preserved when calling from the domain name.

Is this problem related to resolving DNS at my domain registry, or it's an Nginx config issue?

Answer (score 0):

Its a nginx config issue. You need to create the virtual host for your subdomain. Post that you should be able to access your app from your subdomain.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was with the Domain registry (**GoDaddy**) and had nothing to do with Nginx config.
After moving from GoDaddy to AWS Route53, I can easily access sub-domain with it's relative paths.